# WPF: Binding TextBox Text to a sub-element of a Property with WCF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a TextBox which I'm trying to bind to a element of a table property 'regimeAlias' is a column with the `tbRegimes` table which I have mapped with Entity Framework:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding NewRegime.regimeAlias, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Exposed property in my ViewModel:

```
private tbRegime _NewRegime;
public tbRegime NewRegime
{
    get { return _NewRegime; }
    set
    {
        _NewRegime = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("NewRegime");
    }
}
```

Lastly, here's the WCF Service Reference auto-generated code class:

```
public partial class tbRegime : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

//blah blah blah

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public string regimeAlias {
    get {
        return this.regimeAliasField;
    }
    set {
        if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.regimeAliasField, value) != true)) {
            this.regimeAliasField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("regimeAlias");
        }
    }
}
```

The setter never gets hit. Is this because each element within the `NewRegime` object needs to raise `PropertyChanged` and if so is there an easy workaround without adding a further DTO layer to my code?

Comment: But does the setter for regimeAlias get hit?

Answer (score 1):

Edit3: with the post from your regimeAlias code. i have to say your binding should work. but of course if you wanna debug you have to set the breakpoint in your regimeAlias setter

---

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding NewRegime.regimeAlias, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

this code means, you bind to a **Public Property regimeAlias** in your class **tbRegime**.
your setter for NewRegime will never hit because you dont bind to it.

so check your tbRegime class property setter for regimeAlias.

EDIT: the DataContext of the TextBox is of course an object with the Public Property NewRegime, but like i said if you use dot notation in your binding the last property is the one you bind to :)

EDIT: you dont have much ways to workaround:) if you let the binding like you did, you need a model with a public property regimeAlias and it should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

if you wanna wrap the regimeAlias Property then you have the problem the you have to raise OnPropertyChanged("MyRegimeAlias") at the right point.

```
public string MyRegimeAlias
{
    get { return _NewRegime.regimeAlias; }
    set
    {
        _NewRegime.regimeAlias = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyRegimeAlias");
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyRegimeAlias, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: regimeAlias is a private field?

Comment: My mistake, the WCF Service Reference code exposes public properties. Edited the question...

Comment: Ok thanks, so really I'm going to have to expose a stand-alone property for every child member of tbRegime. At least this way I can set the tbRegime objject then pass it into my LINQ method to persist the change back to the db rather than passing through a load of parameters for every value :)

Comment: I'm getting a null reference exception trying to implement this at run time unfortunately

Comment: your _NewRegime should be initilized of course. simply debug your code

Comment: Yes, Ended up creating a string property to hold each TextBox value then newing up a new Regime object in the Insert method. Thanks for your help.